# please help how to validate user insert 12 character in field using atk

Tags: php, validation

this is question about Achievo Atk Framework:

i need to validate a field.

if a fields is a must i just need to put AF_OBLIGATORY

fields must be been fill in 15 characters. if a user fill in less than that how to make a warning or message they have to fill in 15 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a validate function

See the forum -
http://forum.achievo.org/viewforum.php?f=2

and other resources at -
http://www.atk-framework.com/wiki/ATK

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

**NO,**

**but**

when you are creating database we must select data type as **varchar**.

If you selected **char** type it occupy **total size with null**.

If you selected **varchar** type it will store how much **string length at the dynamic time**.